# emit socket event when user logs in on meanjs app

Tags: meanjs

I want to emit a socket event signaling that a user has signed on and is currently available on my app built with the [meanjs](http://meanjs.org/) architecture. I have several other events emitting from my home.client.controller.js file and being picked up on listeners in my socket.io.js file without a hitch but I can't seem to wire an emitter from the authentication controller or the usersignin and usersignup functions in the users.client.service.js file. I am injecting the Socket object in to both so I don't think that is the problem.

This feels like it should be really simple. My test users can sign up and sign in with no problem I just can't get a socket.io event to emit when they do sign on. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Let me know what files you would like to see and I will edit this question to provide.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I used an if statement to check if vm.authentication.user was defined and the if it was to emit a socket event letting the rest of the system know that the user was signed in.

```
if (vm.authentication.user) {
  Socket.emit('signedIn', vm.authentication.user);
}
```